# ng-repeat not working on Angular 1.3

Tags: angularjs, api, angularjs-ng-repeat

Trying to display an array of objects from Meetup API in my html using Angular but I don't know why this isn't working?

I've tried {{member.results.city}}

{{members.results.city}}

**HTML**

```
    <div class="col-md-12" ng-controller="MemberCtrl">
         <ul ng-repeat='member in members'>
            <li>{{members.results[0].city}}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

**controllers.js**

```
    var nameApp = angular.module('nameApp', ['ngRoute','nameAppControllers', 'ngResource', 'ngSanitize', 'firebase']);

    var nameAppControllers = angular.module('nameAppControllers', []);

    nameAppControllers.controller('MemberCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.jsonp('https://api.meetup.com/2/members?callback=JSON_CALLBACK&offset=0&format=json&group_id=00000000&photo-host=public&page=20&order=name&sig_id=000000&sig=cce14dfef840d30c57a4f7977c6cbe877ddfs4127').success(function(data) {
        $scope.members = data;
        console.log(data);
    });
    });
```

Comment: What is the structure of your json... I think databinding in your view should be member.city instead of members.results[0].city. Show your json data

Comment: i dunno the meetup API, but you might want to remove the keys from that url.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you get the info from api should be  $scope.members = data.results;
And then add in your view member.city un databinding

Answer (score 1):

Use `member.city`

```
<ul ng-repeat="member in members">
    <li>{{member.city}}</li>
</ul>
```

Explanation:  `ng-repeat` is iterating over each of the objects in `members` (which should be equivalent to the `results` array in your linked json).  Each object will be referred to by `member`, allowing you access to the property `city` in each object.

EDIT:  @MaxPinto is correct.  `members` assignment should be `$scope.members = data.results;`  Then you should be in business...